# How to pass structure by reference?

Tags: swift, struct, pass-by-reference

If I have some existing struct, but I want to use "Reference" behavior, how do I achieve that?

I can write some simple class-holder like

```
class Box<T> {
    var value: T
    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

I guess there must be ready class in the standard library, but I didn't find it.

I want to store that reference in my class, so inout parameter isn't what I need.

Comment: Would a `class` be more suitable for your purposes?  They're passed by reference.  Instances of `struct` are designed to be passed by value.

Comment: That would solve my issue, but that means that I have to duplicate existing framework structure like CGRect and implement conversions back and forth. I want to avoid duplication if possible.

Comment: @sapi: Everything in Swift is always passed by value, unless the parameter is marked `inout` in which case it is always passed by reference.

Comment: @newacct Basically, `inout` parameter is not "call-by-reference", but rather ["call-by-copy-restore"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_copy-restore).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me the best variant was using class-holder:

```
class Ref<T> {
  var value: T

  init(_ value: T) {
    self.value = value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can, but you should not store it in your class.

```
struct Size {
    var width:Float
    var height:Float
}

class Rect {
    var sizeRef:UnsafeMutablePointer<Size>
    init(_ size:UnsafeMutablePointer<Size>) {
        self.sizeRef = size
    }
    func doubleSize() {
        self.sizeRef.memory.height *= 2.0
        self.sizeRef.memory.width *= 2.0
    }
}  

var size = Size(width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
let rect = Rect(&size)
rect.doubleSize()
println("size: \(size.width) x \(size.height)") // -> size: 40.0 x 40.0
```

Because, usually, `struct` is allocated from "stack" memory, when you do like this:

```
func makeRect() -> Rect {
    var size = Size(width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
    return Rect(&size)
}

let rect = makeRect()
```

`rect.sizeRef` no longer points valid memory. `UnsafeMutablePointer` is **unsafe** in a literal sense.

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
@propertyWrapper public struct Inout<T> {
    public init(wrappedValue: T) {
        storage = .init(value: wrappedValue)
    }
    
    private let storage: Storage
    
    public var wrappedValue: T {
        nonmutating get { storage.value }
        nonmutating set { storage.value = newValue }
    }
    
    private class Storage {
        init(value: T) {
            self.value = value
        }
        
        var value: T
    }
}
```

Example:

```
struct Example { 
    init(value: Inout<Int>) { 
        _value = value
    }
    
    @Inout var value: Int
    
    func performAction() { 
        value += 19
    }
}
let value = Inout(wrappedValue: 50)
let example = Example(value: value)
example.performAction()
print(value.wrappedValue) // 69
```